# How to get specific lines with Jsoup

Tags: jsoup

This is the source code that I am trying to scrape with Jsoup. I am interested in taking data from following: "Code Number", "Date Available", "Type", "Breed", "Sex", "Age", "Weight" and "Adoption Fee". That is, I am looking for my output to be:

Code Number: 107796

Date Availabe: 11/20/2018

Type: Dog

Breed: German Shepherd Dog

Sex: Male

Age: 2 years, 0 months

Weight: 64.6 lbs

Adoption Fee: $250

Source code from:
view-source:https://southwesthumane.org/adopt/dogs/dog-details/?id=84807
lines 186-215

```html
<div id="ContentPlaceHolder_Item3_AnimalDetails_2_divDetails">
<h3>Alan</h3>
<div class="float-to-right animal-slideshow">
<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx="Fade" data-cycle-timeout="0" data-cycle-auto-height="container" data-cycle-pager="#adv-custom-pager" data-cycle-pager-template="<a href='#'><img src='{{src}}' width=50 height=50></a>">
<img src="http://southwesthumanepets.shelterbuddy.com/photos/lostfound/84807.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="adv-custom-pager"></div>
</div>
<div class="AnimalDetails">
<p>Alan is looking for a new best friend! Could it be you? Alan is new to the shelter and we are still getting to know his unique personality. If Alan looks like your dream dog, let the staff know you are interested in meeting him. Going to a new home can be exciting and strange for pets, so it's best for them to meet any children and other dogs in their future home. Alan can't wait to meet his forever family!</p>
<br />
<strong>Code Number: </strong>107796
<br />
<strong>Date Available: </strong>11/20/2018
<br />
<strong>Type: </strong>Dog
<br />
<strong>Breed: </strong>German Shepherd Dog
<br />
<strong>Sex: </strong>Male
<br />
<strong>Age: </strong>2 years, 0 months
<br />
<strong>Weight: </strong>64.6 lbs
<br />
<strong>Adoption Fee: </strong>$250
<br />
<br />
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my code so far:

```html
     try{
                Document dogs = Jsoup.connect("https://southwesthumane.org/adopt/dogs/").get();
                Elements links_dogs = dogs.select(":containsOwn(Details »)");
                for (Element link : links_dogs) {
                    String test = "https://southwesthumane.org" + link.attr("href");
                    System.out.println("url: " + test);
                    try{
                        Document dog = Jsoup.connect(test).get();
                        Elements name = dog.select("h3");
                        Elements description = dog.select("div.Animaldetails");
                        for (Element code : name) {
                            System.out.println("Name: " + code.text());
                        }
                        for (Element code : description) {
                            System.out.println("Description: " + code.select("p").text());
                            System.out.println(code.select("strong").first().text());
                            System.out.println(code.select("div.Animaldetails").text());
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

This line:

> System.out.println(code.select("div.Animaldetails").text());

is taking all the information I need but I do not know how to parse each individual line because ultimately I will save each individual information into a list. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can select the strong HTML tags, and for each tag retrieved, get the nextSibling. Try it out by changing your **for each loop**:

```
for (Element code : description) {
    System.out.println("Description: " + code.select("p").text());
    System.out.println(code.select("strong").first().text());
    System.out.println(code.select("div.AnimalDetails").text());
}
```

to:

```
for (Element code : description) {
     Elements strongs = code.select("strong");
     for(Element e : strongs){
         System.out.println(e.text() + e.nextSibling().toString());
     }
     System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked @Eritrean answer, but I guess mine is a closer approach to get exactly what you are looking for in a more clear way! Here is a sample code to do exactly what you want to using **JSOUP**:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String url = "https://southwesthumane.org/adopt/dogs/dog-details/?id=84807";

            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").get();
            Elements elements = document.select("div.AnimalDetails > strong");

            for (Element element : elements) {
                System.out.println(element.text() + element.nextSibling().toString());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see, one you establish the connection to your desired URL you just need to select all the strong HTML tags contained inside the div HTML tag with class name **AnimalDetails**.

Once you do that you are going to get an Elements object from JSOUP, and you need to loop over it using a FOR EACH loop. In which you are going to get all the elements containing a strong HTML tag.

What you have to do now is to retrieve the text contained between those tags using the **.text()** selector from JSOUP, and as the HTML code is structured you need to retrieve the next element, that it's the value you are looking for.

As the HTML structure of the **AnimalDetails** div is like this:

```
<br>
<strong>Code Number: </strong>107796
<br>
<strong>Date Available: </strong>11/20/2018
<br>
...
and so on
```

You now need to get the sibling element of the strong HTML tag using the **.nextSibling()** selector from JSOUP and the convert it into a String using the **.toString()** method. This, as you can see, retrieves the value you are looking for. Then you just need to print it as your desired output as described in the new FOR EACH loop.

Your desired output will look as it follows:

[image: desired scrapping output]

Hope this helped you! For further information feel free to ask me!